How to find the Ph.D. thesis of Sir Roger Penrose?
I am currently writing my Ph.D. thesis. I like to take inspiration from the writing of people I have admired my whole student life. The idea is to take inspiration from how people wrote many complicated ideas in an informative but concise form. In this quest, I wanted to look at Roger Penrose's Ph.D. thesis even though my topic is far from what he did. However, I have lost hope. It is not there online anywhere.

Have you asked your librarian? Helping you find literature like that is their job after all...

@MaartenBuis It is easier to order through the library if the entry exists. For this case, unfortunately not. However, I will see if that is an option.

Your library employs people who can help you. They are called librarians. Just talk to them.

@Sursula Although the question is similar, I also have asked about the interesting and well-written thesis that people might have encountered.

@CfourPiO For SE, it is better to ask one question at a time.

@MaartenBuis, I am familiar with the terminology; thank you for your input.

@CfourPiO: I removed your second question since there should be only one question per question (as already mentioned) and it’s also far too broad and opinion-based for this site.

note, this question has also been brought in mathoverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/256134/penrose-thesis-topics

@CfourPiO asking for specific theses is also a shopping question which is also off-topic

I also think your approach of looking at PhD theses in particular is flawed. Rather look at any scientific writing that you consider good. While there are some differences between PhD theses and other publications in the macroscopic structure, this structure also strongly depends on the particular work. As for Penrose’ thesis in particular: Scientific writing has progressed a lot since 1958 and you should not ignore this. Also pure mathematics is and was very different from other fields in its writing.

@Wrzlprmft Thank you for the suggestion. I did not think from this perspective.

https://www.qmul.ac.uk/spcs/staff/visiting-staff/profiles/rouse.html Try contacting him directly?

@Sursula Thanks. Will try this option as well.

One trip to Wikipedia gives us a link to the entry for the thesis in the Cambridge university library:
https://idiscover.lib.cam.ac.uk/permalink/f/t9gok8/44CAM_ALMA21428192330003606
It does not seem to be available for loan, but you can contact the library to see if they have a digitized version (or ask your local university librarian).
Here is the worldcat entry: https://www.worldcat.org/oclc/71366928
The Center for Reseach Libraries has a microfilm version, which they can digitize on request: https://catalog.crl.edu/Record/d36d6ec6-3700-5e81-b894-27ef84ece6a9

Excellent. Our university is not a CRL member though. Luckily, I found an entry in my university library online. I have ordered it. Thank you. I don't know if they can request it.

Unfortunately, they can not order it :(

Since (from what you say in comments) you’re at a university, ask your university’s librarians for help — either by email or (often best of all) in person.  Helping researchers obtain literature is one of their main job responsibilities (though less often needed now than it was twenty years ago); they can often find much more beyond what you can get automatically through online systems.
Depending where you live, you may have other research libraries available to you as well — many countries or large cities have national/municipal research libraries, with similarly well-qualified librarians. (For instance, in the countries I know, the UK has the British Library, and Sweden has the Kungliga Biblioteket in Stockholm, both open to anyone living in the country.)

There is nothing a research librarian likes better than a challenge like the OP has. They live for this kind of thing.

Actually, I have tried this today and they said they can’t help as it’s not available at all in EU and they don’t want to import from somewhere else now. However, I asked them over email. I will try to reach out to them physically. Let’s see if they can.
